What's special about Puka Huk's Bow, if anything?
The description of Puka Huk's Bow says:

Bow of the renowned herbalist Puka Huk, Rumored to be able to step between worlds.

I thought it means it helps with stealth, but words online says that it's just a better bow than the others when all are un-upgraded.
Is that it? Is there no special ability like the Exiled Fox's Bow which "deals higher damage to animals"?
